# Quasi-Linear Production and Inefficiency

Tags: production-function

For quasi-linear production of $F(K,L)= \sqrt{K}+L $. I know for the optimal efficiency to exist $q \geq \frac{w}{2r}$ where w is the cost labour and r is the cost of capital. 
My question is what happened when the firm chooses to produce in $ q \leq \frac{w}{2r}$ condition? Would such a situation covert the production function into substitution function?

Comment: What does "optimal efficiency" mean? And how did you get $q\ge \frac{w}{2r}$ as a condition for that?

Comment: Use a basic cost function $C(K,L)=wK+rL$. The cost minimising occurs at $\sqrt{K}=\frac{w}{2r}$. If you operate in $q < \frac{w}{2r}$ then you to get negative unit of Labour value which does not make sense in reality. So I assumed the firm operate at $\sqrt{K}=\frac{w}{2r}$ and L=0, which is different then the cost minimising input thus implies inefficiency. But something tell me my intuition might be wrong.